# Why to specify Last-Modified?

Tags: cache-control, last-modified, expires-header, etag

I'm bit confused with this header.
I already added "Expires" and "Cache-Control: max-age" in my .httaccess.
I also removed "E-tag" and "Last-Modified" as per advice:

> If you remove the Last-Modified and ETag header, you will totally eliminate If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests and their 304 Not Modified Responses, so a file will stay cached without checking for updates until the Expires header indicates new content is available!

so why Google's PageSpeed shows that?:

> Specify a cache validator: 
>   The following resources are missing a cache validator. 
>   Resources that do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the following resources